# What's the name for cropping a video clip/animated gif in time and making it shorter?

Tags: animation, gif, crop, slices, video

I'm having a nightmare searching for this and it seems pretty simple. I have an animated gif and I would like to not have the last few seconds/frames. I.e. I would like to crop it in time, not spatially. I've heard this referred to as slicing a clip but that still isn't helping. What term should I be searching for?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

“Trim.”

Cropping is reducing the dimensions of the canvas. Slicing is splitting a clip into 2 clips. Trimming is shortening a clip from either the beginning or the end of the clip.

Typically you will see “trim handles” on the left and right of a clip that enable you to trim the beginning and/or end respectively.